# Grunt Plugin - Chai Test Assertion

Tags: gruntjs, npm, chai

I have a Grunt plugin for which I'm trying to write a test.  I'm trying to test whether when I try to act on an invalid file type, I'm getting an error in my callback.  The 'err' variable is returning with a toString() value of:

```
[Error: No handler for filetype. Unsure what to do with this file: test/input/illegal.file.name
```

But when I try to test for this as a string, I'm getting what I suspect is a type error.

```
it('should return an error for illegal file names', function(done) {
    grunt.task([
        {
            src : ['test/input/illegal.file.name'],
            dest : '.tmp/ignored.out'
        },
    ], function(err) {
        should.equal(err, "Error: No handler for filetype. Unsure what to do with this file: test/input/illegal.file.name");
    });
});
```

This returns:

```
AssertionError: expected [Error: No handler for filetype. Unsure what to do with this file: test/input/illegal.file.name] to equal 'Error: No handler for filetype. Unsure what to do with this file: test/input/illegal.file.name'
```

So, I tried to create a new error and match that, to no avail:

```
it('should return an error for illegal file names', function(done) {
    grunt.task([
        {
            src : ['test/input/illegal.file.name'],
            dest : '.tmp/ignored.out'
        },
    ], function(err) {
        var newError = new Error("No handler for filetype. Unsure what to do with this file: test/input/illegal.file.name");
        should.equal(err, newError);
    });
});
```

But this returns:

```
AssertionError: expected 
[Error: No handler for filetype. Unsure what to do with this file: test/input/illegal.file.name] to equal 
[Error: No handler for filetype. Unsure what to do with this file: test/input/illegal.file.name]
  + expected - actual
```

That sure seems to be equal, but I'm obviously missing something very basic....

Any help would be very appreciated.

### Update

Something really funky is going on, because if I take a single space out of the test string, I get a very valid message:

```
it('should return an error for illegal file names', function(done) {
    grunt.task([
        {
            src : ['test/input/illegal.file.name'],
            dest : '.tmp/ignored.out'
        },
    ], function(err) {
        //                           v-- no space
        should.equal(err.message, "Nohandler for filetype: test/input/illegal.file.name");
    });
});
```

Returns:

```
AssertionError: expected 'No handler for filetype: test/input/illegal.file.name' to equal 'Nohandler for filetype: test/input/illegal.file.name'
  + expected - actual

  +"Nohandler for filetype: test/input/illegal.file.name"
  -"No handler for filetype: test/input/illegal.file.name"
```

When I put the space back in between "No" and "handler", I get a very strange error:

```
it('should return an error for illegal file names', function(done) {
    grunt.task([
        {
            src : ['test/input/illegal.file.name'],
            dest : '.tmp/ignored.out'
        },
    ], function(err) {
        should.equal(err.message, "No handler for filetype: test/input/illegal.file.name");
    });
});
```

This returns:

```
1) should return an error for illegal file names:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two objects with the same argument are not equal. Try something like this instead:

```
should.equal(err.message, newError.message)
```

Or just skip the creation of a new error and do:

```
should.equal(err.message, "No handler for filetype. Unsure what to do with this file: test/input/illegal.file.name")
```

Also, you're running an asynchronous test, so be sure to call `done()` after your assertion.

Comment: But I do want an error.  I want an illegal file name to generate an error.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(arguments)` before the assertion?

Comment: { '0': [Error: No handler for filetype: test/input/illegal.file.name] (I shortened the error message)}

Comment: Adding or removing the space as you did shouldn't make a difference to whether `err` is defined or not, so something else is going on that is not obvious from here. Let me know if you encounter anything else that might help. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah, this whole test seems to be messed up as subsequent running produces different results.  Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Oh I didn't even look closely enough to see that it's asynchronous. Are you including done() after your assertion ?